# Sensible way to power an OLED display from AAA Cells

Tags: power-supply, boost

I'm designing a small battery powered device and I want to use an [SSD1327-based OLED display](https://www.buydisplay.com/default/white-1-5-inch-grayscale-oled-display-panel-128x128-i2c-serial-spi). Unlike the SSD1306, this one doesn't appear to have an integrated boost circuit to power the panel, which wants 8V-18V.

My intention is to power my device with 2 NiMH AAA cells (or 1.5V alkaline) so I will need to boost the ~2.4V up to 3.3V for my controller and ~13V for the OLED panel.

The panel only draws a very small amount of current: ~600uA, and I'm lead to believe that this wouldn't be enough load on a [traditional boost converter](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/MCP1661) from an efficiency point of view.

so, my question:

Given ~2.4V from 2xNiMH AAAs, should I:

1.

```
1 boost converter @ 3.3V
1 boost converter @ ~12V
both powered directly from the battery.
```

2.

```
1 boost converter @ 3.3V (battery powered)
1 boost converter @ ~12V powered from 3.3V
```

3.

```
1 boost converter @ ~12V (battery powered)
1 linear regulator @ 3.3V powered from ~12V
```

As far as efficiency requirements go - I'm building a toy, so I only really want lifetime measurable in a handful of hours, not days or weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Option two is best because you can generate the OLED bias voltage with a charge pump tripler or quadrupler. Using a controller or processor that can be powered directly by the battery would be even better, even if it means quintupling V batt.

Comment: thanks, so you're saying not to even bother with a booster for the 3.3v? I'm planning to use a SAMD21 MCU which runs as low as 1.62V which 2AAAs can easily provide. I've only come across voltage *doubler* ICs, so what would a 'quintupler' look like?